# Strange noise after clearing speed bump

Tags: automatic-transmission, noise, renault

I bought a new Renault Captur EDC (automatic) last week. It has been driving fine but yesterday I heard a brief strange noise immediately after clearing each of 2 speed bumps going up a steep road - it was almost like the gear scratching sound of a normal car. I drove the car some more the next day and it happened again, but only after clearing a bump on an incline, not at any speed on a straight or downhill or non-speed bump incline.

I phoned the dealership and the sales person went with me on a drive to test - he said that he believes it to be the front wheels spinning. I got out of the car and had him drive over a bump while I watched and heard the noise but did not see any spinning of the wheels. Considering that the noise only occur in these rare circumstances, should I be concerned and if so, what might the problem be? Any advice would be appreciated please!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is something I'd be concerned about. Seeing a how it's a new car, pin the dealership down until you can either figure out it's normal or there's an issue. If there's an issue, they'll need to fix it. Don't rely on the salesman, *because they really don't have a clue*. In most cases all they know how to do is sell cars. They really don't know the inner workings of a car. If the car sounds abnormal, there's something abnormal (ie: If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's most likely a duck.).

There's a couple things you can do.

First, get the service writer to take a ride with you. (The service writer is the main person in the service department who takes your information for repairs or maintenance.) They will have a bigger clue than a salesman. They may have a mechanic drive with you to see what the issue may be. Considering that the noise is consistently repeatable, it shouldn't be hard to convince them there's something wrong or at the very least there some type of noise there which is causing you concern.

The other thing you can do is take another car of the same year/model for a test drive and see if it does the same thing. If it makes the same noise, it maybe a systemic problem with the vehicle itself, something Renault should look into.

Considering you've already got the salesman to acknowledge there's actually a noise, you have a case. Build on it and get to the bottom of the noise. Either they'll find something wrong and it'll get fixed or they'll show you what exactly is going on. Don't take "*I think it's this ...*" for an answer. Actually make them figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - you are right - I am going to be more firm!